# What is the closed form of the generating function of the solution to a linear recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form

I've seen many special cases of this,
so I thought it would be good
to provide a more general version.

If this has been done before,
that's OK.

If
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$
where,
for $n \ge m$,
$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_ka_{n-k}
$,
what is a closed form
for $f(x)$?

My answer is
$f(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^n(a_n-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ka_{n-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k}
$.

Here is my derivation.

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} x^n\sum_{k=1}^m c_ka_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} x^na_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} x^{n-k}a_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k\sum_{n=m-k}^{\infty} x^{n}a_{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1} x^{n}a_{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k\left(f(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1} x^{n}a_{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+f(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k-\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1} x^{n}a_{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+f(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1} x^{n+k}a_{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+f(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k\sum_{n=k}^{m-1} x^{n}a_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+f(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\sum_{k=1}^n c_k x^{n}a_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_nx^n+f(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}x^n\sum_{k=1}^n c_ka_{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^n(a_n-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ka_{n-k})+f(x)\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k\\
\text{so}\\
f(x)
&=\dfrac{\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^n(a_n-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ka_{n-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k}\\
\end{array}
$

If $m = 2$ then

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\dfrac{\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} x^n(a_n-\sum_{k=1}^n c_ka_{n-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^k}\\
&=\dfrac{ a_0+x(a_1-c_1a_0)}{1-c_1x-c_2x^2}\\
\end{array}
$

If
$c_1 = c_2 = 1,
a_0 = a_1 = 1$
(Fibonacci sequence),

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\dfrac{ a_0+x(a_1-c_1a_0)}{1-c_1x-c_2x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{ 1}{1-x-x^2}\\
\end{array}
$